# Clear label text in Radiobutton Change event using jquery

Tags: jquery

I cannot clear the label text in radio Button checked change event. lblerror is the Label it will display the error message.i handle the error message  in server side but When i toggle between Excel, CSV, Tab or Custom the label should get cleared. as of now label (lblerror) text is not clearing. Here's the code im using:

```
             function radioValueChanged(radioName) 
             {
                 radioValue = $(this).val();

                 if ($(this).is(":checked") && radioValue == "Excel") 
                  {
                     $('#lblError').text("");
                     $('#txtCustom').hide();                      
                     $('#divcbxSheet').show();
                     $('#lblSheetName').show();
                     $('#radcbxSheetNames').show();

                 }
                  if ($(this).is(":checked") && radioValue == "CSV") 
                 {
                     $('#lblError').text("");

                     $('#txtCustom').hide();
                     $('#lblSheetName').hide()
                     $('#radcbxSheetNames').hide();
                     $('#divcbxSheet').hide();
                 }
                  if ($(this).is(":checked") && radioValue == "Tab") 
                 {
                     $('#lblError').text("");

                     $('#txtCustom').hide();
                     $('#divcbxSheet').hide();
                     $('#lblSheetName').hide();
                     $('#radcbxSheetNames').hide();
                 }
                 if ($(this).is(":checked") && radioValue == "Custom") {
                     $('#lblError').text("");
                     $('#txtCustom').show();
                     $('#divcbxSheet').hide();
                     $('#lblSheetName').hide();
                     $('#radcbxSheetNames').hide();
                 }
             }
```

Comment: Is the only problem that the Error label isn't clearing? Is the show/hide behaviour working for the other elements? Can you also post the code where you are hooking up the change event?

Comment: Yes its working for other elements. label text is not clearing when i toggle between Excel, CSV, Tab Options. when i choose custom radio button label text is clearing and txtcustom box is visible.

Comment: and one more thing is when i move the mouse down this label is getting cleared. how this is possible? i dint write any code for mouse events.

Comment: Can you post the html for the label?

Comment: hi rezler, this is the label code,  <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:Label>

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the case match. `$('#lblError')` won't match `<label id="lblerror"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are incorrectly using "this". You are passing the parameter "radioName" into the function but it is never being used. Should you be using it to get at the radiobutton element rather than "this".

Comment: This event is firing for other cases. only problem with the label.